# Oracle SQL query to fix the null issue in the Primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table TEST
(
job_id integer
,etl_job_run_day date
,cust_sid integer
,cust_id number(38,0)
,cust_first_name varchar2(100)
,cust_last_name varchar2(100)
,effective_dt_from date
,effective_dt_to date
,version integer
,latest_fl varchar2(1)
,actual_cust_id integer
);


insert into abc values (123,02.03.20 00:00:00,100,6842,'Adam','Zampa',26.02.20 00:00:00,02.03.20 00:00:00,1,'N','');
insert into abc values (123,06.03.20 00:00:00,143,6842,'Tony','Greig',02.03.20 00:00:00,31.12.99 00:00:00,2,'Y',9011);
```

***Present Situation***

```
JOB_ID  ETL_JOB_RUN_DAY    CUST_SID CUST_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME CUST_LAST_NAME   EFFECTIVE_DATE_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO    VERSION LATEST_FL ACTUAL_CUST_ID
123 02.03.20 00:00:00   100 6842    Adam    Zampa   26.02.20 00:00:00   02.03.20 00:00:00   1   N   
123 06.03.20 00:00:00   143 6842    Adam    Zampa   02.03.20 00:00:00   31.12.99 00:00:00   1   Y   9011
```

***Expected solution to be***

```
JOB_ID  ETL_JOB_RUN_DAY    CUST_SID CUST_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME CUST_LAST_NAME   EFFECTIVE_DATE_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO    VERSION LATEST_FL ACTUAL_CUST_ID
123 02.03.20 00:00:00   100 6842    Adam    Zampa   26.02.20 00:00:00   02.03.20 00:00:00   1   N   **9011**
123 06.03.20 00:00:00   143 6842    Adam    Zampa   02.03.20 00:00:00   31.12.99 00:00:00   1   Y   9011
```

so previously the historical update was not done properly. so i have mostly two versions same like above, i have some hundreds of records with this situation  **ACTUAL_CUST_ID** is currently having nulls ,so need to update all the records where ACTUAL_CUST_ID is null and update with value of other version for example 9011 must be updated where we have null.

since as i have mentioned many records exist like this ,so i need to come up with a merge statement using lag or lead function to fix all the records ,could any one provide me the best solution ?

Comment: Your sample table has quite a lot of columns Based on which criteria exactly do you decide which record to take the `actual_cust_id` from?

Comment: You must **first** describe what is your primary key in the table. I suspect that also the `VERSION` columns is corrupted by the invalid ETL (shouldn't the second row have a version = 2?). **Than** you must clarify how to select the `ACTUAL_CUST_ID` if there are more values within the versioned records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the update statement as following:

```
Update test t
Set t.actual_cust_id = 
(Select max(t1.actual_cust_id)
From test t1
Where t.job_id = t1.job_id
And t.cust_id = t1.cust_id)
Where 
t.actual_cust_id is null
And exists 
(Select 1 from test t2
Where t.job_id = t2.job_id
And t.cust_id = t2.cust_id
And t2.actual_cust_id is not null)
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b38e58d4966142e0397605472d07c91)

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @Tejash - i have a complex problem related to data integrity i have explained and the query provided in the post is not working - can you have a look  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418132/data-integrity-sql-query-to-fix-the-bug-in-the-table/61424780?noredirect=1#comment108665735_61424780