# Data Integrity SQL query to fix the bug in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently i am facing a data integrity issue on one of the table from dimension table ,below are the details

```
create table TEST_TBL
(
JOB_ID  NUMBER(38,0),
LOC_SID NUMBER(38,0),
CITY VARCHAR2(180 BYTE),
CITY_NM_CLR VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
CITY_NM_OFFICIAL VARCHAR2(180 BYTE),
DISTRICT VARCHAR2(120 BYTE),
DISTRICT_CD VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
IN_CNTRY_REG VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
CNTRY_NM VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
POSTAL_CD VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
POPUL_APROX VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
LONGITUDE NUMBER,
LATITUDE NUMBER,
GLOBAL_REG VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
CNTRY_CD_2CHAR  VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
CNTRY_CD_3CHAR  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
CNTRY_CD_NUMER  VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
CNTRY_NM_OFFICIAL VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
CNTRY_CALL_CD VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
BANK_CNTRY_CD NUMBER(38,0),
CONTINENT VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
MONETARY_REG VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM DATE,
EFFECTIVE_DT_TO DATE,
VERSION NUMBER(38,0),
UPDATED_BY_ETL_JOB NUMBER(38,0)
);

Insert into TEST_TBL values (1234,'81910','N/A',null,'N/A','N/A','0','N/A','USA','N/A','0','0','0','NA','EN','ENG','001',null,'91','0','North_America',null,to_date('01.01.00 00:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('31.12.99 23:59:59','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),'1',null);
```

Please note:

Unique index is already assigned to LOC_SID (primary key) non unique index is already inplace for the following columns CITY_NM_CLR,CNTRY_CD_2CHAR

Present situation

when i am checking the integrity issue from the table i am getting many recrods approx 300+ (above is the same data set record)

Below is the sql query i am using to check the integrity

```
SELECT count(*) AS RowAffected
FROM
  (SELECT LOC_SID,
          VERSION,
          EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM,
          EFFECTIVE_DT_TO,
          CITY,
          POSTAL_CD
   FROM
     (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CITY, POSTAL_CD
                                             ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_date,
             LEAD(VERSION, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CTY, POSTAL_CD
                                   ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_version
      FROM TEST_TBL t)
   WHERE valid_to != next_date
     OR VERSION = next_version)
```

after the fix when i run the above query it should not return any result

Let me give a overview of counts with sample data

```
CITY       POSTAL_CD   COUNT(*)

N/A         N/A       502

TOKYO       N/A       30

HABSIGUDA   3452      2

DELHI       N/A       4

ASSAM       1153      1

ASSAM       1290      1

ASSAM       1310      1

ASSAM       1781      1

ASSAM       1982      1
```

Sample data

**scenario - 1**

```
LOC_SID CITY    POSTAL_CD   EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM  EFFECTIVE_DT_TO  VERSION
82141   N/A     N/A         01.01.1900         31.12.2199       1
82142   N/A     N/A         01.01.1900         31.12.2199       1
```

**i have 400 such rows**

**scenario - 2**

```
LOC_SID CITY    POSTAL_CD   EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DT_TO   VERSION
46211   TOKYO    N/A        01.01.1900          31.12.2199    1
46212   TOKYO    N/A        01.01.1900          31.12.2199    1
```

**i have 30 such rows**

**scenario - 3**

```
 LOC_SID CITY       POSTAL_CD  EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM  EFFECTIVE_DT_TO  VERSION
 57372  HABSIGUDA   3452  01.01.1900          29.12.2017             1
 61321  HABSIGUDA   3452  29.12.2017          31.12.2199             2
 67371  UPPAL       4922  01.01.1900          31.12.2199             1
 80737  HABSIGUDA   3452  01.01.1900          31.12.2199             1
```

**i have just one row**

**scenario - 4**

```
LOC_SID CITY    POSTAL_CD   EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DT_TO  VERSION
4822    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
4825    DELHI   3911        01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
4826    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
4827    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
4828    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
4829    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
```

**i have some 4 rows**

**Scenario - 5**

```
LOC_SID CITY    POSTAL_CD   EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DT_TO  VERSION
25101   ASSAM   1153            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25102   ASSAM   1153            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25103   ASSAM   1290            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25104   ASSAM   1290            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25105   ASSAM   1310            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25106   ASSAM   1310            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25107   ASSAM   1781            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25108   ASSAM   1781            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25109   ASSAM   1982            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
25110   ASSAM   1982            01.01.1900          31.12.2199     1
```

**i have 300 rows**

basically LOC_SID is PK and incremental ,so after the version expected is incremental  below is the expected result after the update statement is executed then in the db table

** results (after running the update statement )**

**scenario - 4**

```
LOC_SID CITY    POSTAL_CD   EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM   EFFECTIVE_DT_TO  VERSION
4822    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          01.01.1900         1
4825    DELHI   3911        01.01.1900          31.12.2199         1
4826    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          01.01.1900         2
4827    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          01.01.1900         3
4828    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          01.01.1900         4
4829    DELHI   N/A         01.01.1900          01.01.1900         5
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397859/oracle-sql-query-to-fix-the-integraity-issue-in-the-table)? You might want to try and improve your question rather than reposting it.

Comment: Hi GMB, ignore previous post this is the accurate one

Comment: Hi Tejash, you have any suggestions ? , update statement ?

Comment: Hi @Tejash can you suggest any accurate solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a `backup` of your table `TEST_TBL` and try the below

Do the following two `UPDATE` till you get `zero rows` updated

```
    BEGIN
    WHILE(1=1)
    LOOP 
    UPDATE TEST_TBL a 
    set version=(select prev_version+1 from   
                             (
                            SELECT
                        t.*,
                      ROWID,
                      Lag(version, 1)
                        over(
                          PARTITION BY cty, postal_cd
                          ORDER BY effective_dt_from) AS prev_version
                         from TEST_TBL T)t
                         where a.rowid=t.rowid 
                        AND a.version <=t.prev_version)
    WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from  (
                            SELECT
                        t.*,
                      ROWID,
                      Lag(version, 1)
                        over(
                          PARTITION BY cty, postal_cd
                          ORDER BY effective_dt_from) AS prev_version
                         from TEST_TBL T)t
                         where a.rowid=t.rowid 
                        AND a.version <=t.prev_version);
    commit;
    EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT=0; 
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Second update

```
    BEGIN
    WHILE(1=1)
    LOOP
    UPDATE TEST_TBL b
    set valid_to=(select next_date from 
                             (
                            SELECT
                        t.*,
                      ROWID,
                      LEAD(EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CITY, POSTAL_CD
                                                 ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_date
                         from test_tbl T)t
                         where b.rowid=t.rowid 
                        AND valid_to != next_date)
    WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from   (
                            SELECT
                        t.*,
                      ROWID,
                      LEAD(EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY CITY, POSTAL_CD
                                                 ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_date
                         from test_tbl T)t
                         where b.rowid=t.rowid 
                        AND valid_to != next_date);
                        commit;
    EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT=0; 
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Hi Raj , why are we deleting can we come up with update/merge statement?

Comment: Hi Raj i have version as 1 through out the table if you see the sample data with issue then you will understand

Comment: Hi Raj i have tried the Query 1 - Merge ran into this error - SQL Error: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
00969. 00000 -  "missing ON keyword"

Comment: Hi Raj i  am getting this error - ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Hi Raj there is no column with version_no

Comment: Edited the same

Comment: Hi RAJ  i have tested Query 1 it ran fine i am encountering the same error in the query 2 , why are you splitting intlo two queries ?

Comment: hi rakesh i changed it into one merge

Comment: Hi Raj , i have tried to test the query - SQL Error: ORA-00904: "T"."NEXT_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Hi Rakesh Sorry try now

Comment: Hi Raj - I have tried testing the query , ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: try now rakesh if all are with version 1 this query should work

Comment: Hi Raj - i will test it and let you know

Comment: Hi Raj , yes all are with version=1 , i have tried to test the query still i am getting - ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Hi Raj - a short explanation diff between these two queries ?

Comment: first one will update the versions incrementally based on city,postal_cd,effective_dt_from and the second one will update the valid_to to the next effective_dt_from if there is a mismatch

Comment: Hi Raj , when i run the second update statement - SQL Error: ORA-00904: "A"."ROWID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Hi @Raj - i have tried with the update statements , basically it's updating the same version across all the results i was trying to come up with some sample data , can you have a look and let me know

Comment: Hi Rakesh, you have to update it till you get zero rows updated, also check if the no of rows updated are less during each update compared to previous update

Comment: Hi @Raj - Is there a way we can do it just in one single query one time , since we need to run this several times , is it possible to run in just one go?

Comment: first try whether this approach works then i can give a for loop to automate this two update running multiple times otherwise it will screw up the existing data

Comment: Hi @Raj i have tested the query and seems working fine , but to automate you mentioned loop statement ?

Comment: Hi @Raj i have tried testing the query got the error   Error report -
ORA-06550: line 29, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
ORA-06550: line 38, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   , from
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Hi @Raj i also noticed the query is running for very long time and it is not completing , i just tested the query 1

Comment: Hi @Raj the issue has been resolved i will post the link later

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578278/auto-incremental-date-field-and-version-oracle-sql-for-a-table