# Data Integrity bug query fix to rewrite the sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-merge

I have a table and in this table i have data which has data integrity issue, since this is a dimension table we need to maintain the `effective_dt_from` and `effective_dt_to` and version correctly.

This is the table and sample data:

```
create table TEST
(
    LOC_SID NUMBER(38,0),
    POSTAL_CD VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
    COUNTRY_CD_2CHAR VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
    CITY VARCHAR2(180 BYTE),
    DISTRICT_CD VARCHAR2(120 BYTE),
    POPULATION_APPROX VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
    EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM DATE,
    EFFECTIVE_DT_TO DATE,
    VERSION NUMBER(38,0)
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (81910, 1234, UK, 'Liverpool', 50, 1000, to_date('01.01.00 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('31.12.99 23:59:59', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'), 1)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (81911,1234,UK,'Liverpool',50,0,to_date('01.01.00 00:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('31.12.99 23:59:59','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),1)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (81912,4567,UK,'Liverpool',50,2000,to_date('01.01.00 00:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('31.12.99 23:59:59','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),1)
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (81913,4567,UK,'Liverpool',50,0,to_date('01.01.00 00:00:00','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('31.12.99 23:59:59','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS'),1)
```

Data integrity check query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS RowAffected
FROM
    (SELECT 
         LOC_SID,
         VERSION,
         EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM, EFFECTIVE_DT_TO,
         CITY,
         POSTAL_CD
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              t.*,
              LEAD(EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY POSTAL_CD, COUNTRY_CD_2CHAR, CITY, DISTRICT_CD
                                               ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_date,
              LEAD(VERSION, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY POSTAL_CD, COUNTRY_CD_2CHAR, CITY, DISTRICT_CD
                                     ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM) AS next_version
          FROM 
              TEST t)
     WHERE 
         valid_to != next_date OR VERSION = next_version)
```

Results:

```
CITY       POSTAL_CD   COUNT(*)
--------------------------------    
Liverpool    1234         31
```

Existing data:

```
LOC_SID POSTAL_CD COUNTRY_CD_2CHAR CITY      DISTRICT_CD POPULATION_APPROX EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM DATE EFFECTIVE_DT_TO VERSION

81910   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          1000              01.01.1900        31.12.2199            1
81921   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          0                 01.01.1900        31.12.2199            1
81919   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          2000              01.01.1900        31.12.2199            1
81913   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          0                 01.01.1900        31.12.2199            1
```

Expected data:

```
LOC_SID POSTAL_CD COUNTRY_CD_2CHAR CITY      DISTRICT_CD POPULATION_APPROX EFFECTIVE_DT_FROM DATE EFFECTIVE_DT_TO VERSION

81910   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          1000              01.01.1900        27.10.2016           1
81921   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          0                 27.10.2016        28.10.2016           2
81919   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          2000              01.01.1900        31.12.2199           1
81913   1234      UK               LIVERPOOL 50          0                 27.10.2016        28.10.2016           2
```

Please note: I have 131 records in the table with city - Liverpool and basically I have data integrity issue only for 31 records the above example is just for an example with data for few records for understanding (sid's are not in sequence)

I have tried the below query ,but this query is updating all the E`FFECTIVE_DT_FROM`, `EFFECTIVE_DT_TO` and `version`, but I only need to update 31 records (since the sid's not in sequence my query won't work).

Another point to mention is basically I can hardcode the sids (`loc_sid`) which is the primary key but for that I need to get 62 sid keys and include in the below condition after `where city='Liverpool and loc_sid in (1234,4567......)` and run the query it works fine but I don't want some logic needs to be used, the `loc_sids` are not in sequence, I was not able to figure out this

```
merge into test t
using (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by loc_sid asc) rn,
        count(*) over() cnt
    from test t
    where city = 'Liverpool'
) t1
on (t1.loc_sid = t.loc_id)
when matched the update set
    t.version = t1.rn,
    t.effective_dt_from = 
        case 
            when rn = 1 then t.effective_dt_from
            else date '2016-10-27' + rn - 2
        end,
    t.effective_dt_to = 
        case 
            when rn = cnt then t.effective_dt_to
            else date '2016-10-27' + rn - 1
        end
```

how to resolve this ?